# Why we assign $1/2[f(\epsilon+0) + f(\epsilon-0)]$ as the value at the discontinuity point?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

[image]

My question is why do we define $f(\xi+0)$ as $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f(\xi + \varepsilon^2)$ and $f(\xi-0)$ as $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f(\xi - \varepsilon^2)$.

Thanks.

Comment: The mystery symbol there is actually called \xi.

Comment: We generally don't define $f(\xi+0)$ in this way:
I've never seen this cheesy trick of defining one-sided limits
using squares before. What is this book?

Comment: @Chapman: It is from _Introduction to Calculus and Analysis_ by R.Courant and F.John.

Comment: Concerning the title question, here is a quote from page 49 of Riemann's Zeta Function by H. Edwards:

"In other words $\psi (x)=\sum_{p^{n}<x}\log p$ except when $x$ is a power; at the jumps $x=p^{n}$ the value of $\psi $\ is defined *as usual*, to be halfway between the new and old values $\psi (x)=\frac{1}{2}[\psi(x-\epsilon )+\psi (x+\epsilon )]$".

Concerning your last question, I have never seen those definions in this way. Since $\epsilon ^2$ tends to zero fast than $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon$ approches zero, I guess that there is some connection with the derivative of function.

Comment: @Robin Chapman:But if we do not use squares then $\epsilon$ could be negative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not that we *assign* that value: Fourier series simply converge to that independently of our desires!

Comment: Yes, or even better if $f$ is not given as such then we can redefine $f$ to have the mean value at the point of discontinuity and then $S[f]$ (the Fourier series of $f$) will converge to $f$ at that point.